# Check for records that break a foreign constraint (created with foreign_key_checks = 0)?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, referential-integrity

Is there an easy way to check for any records in a table that breaks any constraint?

The constraint was created on a populated table using "foreign_key_checks=0".

Answer (score 1):

Um, query for them?  Hint: `NOT EXISTS`.